# passing data from a bottom sheet dialog in first Activity to second Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem with passing data in android. let me explain my problem.
there are two activities called MainActivity  and ProductInformationActivity.
in mainActivity there is a settingButton and onClickListener of the button, a bottom sheet dialog will open up. in bottomSheetDialog there are saveButton and three editText. whenever a user click on saveButton it should pass editTexts data's as PercentageClass to productInformationActivity . (percentage Class is a model to save percentages and pass theme between activities).
I create an interface Called "OnPercentageClicked" then I created an instance of this interface and create setter for that (setOnAddPercentageClicked).
in saveButtonListener I create instance of percentege class and set EditTexts data to it and finally I add percentage to interface's method.

this is mainACtivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private View bottomSheetView;
    private BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;
    private OnAddPercentageClicked onAddPercentageClicked;
    
    
    public void setOnAddPercentageClicked(OnAddPercentageClicked onAddPercentageClicked) {
        this.onAddPercentageClicked = onAddPercentageClicked;
    }





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar mainToolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);

        ImageButton settingbtn = findViewById(R.id.activityMain_settingBTN);
        ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.activityMain_viewpager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.activityMain_tabLayout);
        MainViewPagerAdapter adapter = new MainViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        createDialog();

        TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0 : tab.setText("کالا ها"); break;
                    case 1 : tab.setText("دسته بندی ها"); break;
                }
            }
        });
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();

        settingbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                bottomSheetDialog.show();
                TextInputEditText firstPercentage = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.priceIncrementPercentage_firstPercentageET);
                TextInputEditText secondPercentage = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.priceIncrementPercentage_secondPercentageET);
                TextInputEditText thirdPercentage = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.priceIncrementPercentage_thirdPercentageET);
                Button percentageSaveButton = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.priceIncrementPercentage_saveBTN);
                assert percentageSaveButton != null;

                percentageSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (firstPercentage.getText().length()>0 && secondPercentage.getText().length()>0 && thirdPercentage.getText().length()>0){
                            Percentage percentage = new Percentage();
                            percentage.setFirstPercentage(Integer.parseInt(firstPercentage.getText().toString()));
                            percentage.setSecondPercentage(Integer.parseInt(secondPercentage.getText().toString()));
                            percentage.setThirdPercentage(Integer.parseInt(thirdPercentage.getText().toString()));
                            onAddPercentageClicked.onButtonClicked(percentage);
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ذخیره شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "لطفا همه ی فیلد ها را پر کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    public void createDialog(){

        bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.bottom_sheet_dialog_theme);
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.price_increment_percentage,(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.priceIncrementPercentage_container),false));

    }

}
```

in productInfomation Activity i want to get the percentage class which i used in MainActivity.
so I implement OnAddPercentageClicked then I create an instance of main activity and call the setter which I created in MainActivity (setOnAddPercentageClicked).

this is productInformationActivity :

```
public class ProductInformation extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener ,OnAddPercentageClicked{
    private Percentage percentage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_information);

        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.setOnAddPercentageClicked(this);
        
        TextView productName = findViewById(R.id.activityProductInformation_productNameTV);
        TextView productPrice = findViewById(R.id.activityProductInformation_productPriceTV);
        TextView productPriceFirstPercentage = findViewById(R.id.productPriceFirstPercentage);
        TextView productPriceSecondPercentage = findViewById(R.id.productPriceSecondPercentage);
        TextView productPriceThirdPercentage = findViewById(R.id.productPriceThirdPercentage);
        TextView productCategoryName = findViewById(R.id.activityProductInformation_categoryNameTV);
        ImageButton close = findViewById(R.id.activity_product_information_closeIB);
        
        close.setOnClickListener(this);
        
            if (percentage !=null){
                productPriceFirstPercentage.setText("قیمت کالا +"+percentage.getFirstPercentage()+" درصد");
                productPriceSecondPercentage.setText("قیمت کالا +"+percentage.getSecondPercentage()+" درصد");
                productPriceThirdPercentage.setText("قیمت کالا +"+percentage.getThirdPercentage()+" درصد");
            }
//
//        }

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("PRODUCT")){
            Product product = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("PRODUCT");
            productName.setText(product.getTitle());
            productPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
            productCategoryName.setText(String.valueOf(product.getCategoryId()));
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.activity_product_information_closeIB){
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(Percentage percentage) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onButtonClicked: " + percentage);
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

and when i run this code i get an error which says that the interface in MainActicvity is null.

would you please help me ?
thanks.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the flow is MainActivity -> open dialog -> choose  from dialog -> close MainActivity -> open ProductInformationActivity with dialog result ?

Comment: not exactly.
the flow is MainActivity -> open dialog -> by pressing the save Button it must set dialog data's ( which are taken from EditTexts ) to Percentage Model and pass Percentage Model to the productInformationActivity .
but note that it mustn't open the productInformationActivity. 
someone suggested me to use Intent but with intent I should startActivity after passing data which is not my ideal
 I mean after pressing save Button just the data must pass and the dialog must close , So the mainActivity will appear's after closing the dialog

Comment: So two activities must be open at the same time? I think this is not possible and seems like a scenario for Fragments.